# Fatal error: Unsupported operand types

Tags: php

выдает ошибку **Fatal error: Unsupported operand types**

вот код

```
$num = 15;
$page = $_GET['page'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM garb"); 
$posts = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$total = intval(($posts - 1) / $num) + 1;
$page = intval($page);
if(empty($page) or $page < 0) $page = 1; 
  if($page > $total) $page = $total;
  $start = $page * $num - $num; 
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM garb LIMIT $start, $num"); 
  while ( $postrow[] = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

вот строчка где ошибку показывает

```
$total = intval(($posts - 1) / $num) + 1;
```

помогите пж

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

`mysql_fetch_row` возвращает массив

```
$total = ($posts[0] - 1) / $num + 1;
```

Comment: спасибки помогло)